# Linking error for 64-bit NASM code with MinGW 32

Tags: gcc, assembly, mingw, x86-64, nasm

I wrote this code:

```
    global  _main
    extern  _printf

    section .text
_main:
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db  'Hello, World', 10, 0
```

and tried to run it from cmd. It looks like that:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\bin\NASM>nasm helloworld.asm -f win64 -o helloworld.obj

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\bin\NASM>gcc helloworld.obj -m64 -o helloworld.exe
helloworld.obj: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched this error in google but nothing was relevant for me. I'm using Windows (10) as you can see. Does someone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

When I run gcc -v I get this:

```
Reading specs from C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/specs
Configured with: ../gcc-3.4.5-20060117-3/configure --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --enable-threads --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,f77,ada,objc,java --disable-win32-registry --disable-shared --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-libgcj --disable-java-awt --without-x --enable-java-gc=boehm --disable-libgcj-debug --enable-interpreter --enable-hash-synchronization --enable-libstdcxx-debug
Thread model: win32
gcc version 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `gcc -v`

Comment: You have two issues. the GCC you are using doesn't seem to understand windows object files and secondly the code you wrote even if linked to an executable is for 32-bit code. The 64-bit Windows calling convention is different than the 32-bit one.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I added it

Comment: That looks like a 32-bit MinGW compiler. What happens if you use `nasm helloworld.asm -f win32 -o helloworld.obj` and `gcc helloworld.obj -m32 -o helloworld.exe` to generate a 32-bit executable? For 64-bit code you'd need MinGW-w64. Your version of GCC is also quite old going back to the mid 2000s.

Comment: @MichaelPetch When I run it with 32 bits it works well.

Comment: It works in 32-bit because it is a 32-bit compiler. I recommend downloading a new version of [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) (-w64 can compile 32-bit and 64-bit code). You will have to rewrite the assembly code to you use the Microsoft 64-bit calling convention (the first number of parameters are passed via registers, you need a 32 byte shadow space aligned on a 16-byte boundary). The 64-bit calling convention for Windows is discussed in the MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your `gcc -v` output it looks like you are using mingw-32.

You need to get [mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).

Also, functions in 64-bit code for Windows look completely different. Rewrite your code as follows:

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; This is a Win64 console program that writes "Hello" on one line and then exits.  It
; uses puts from the C library.  To assemble and run:
;
;     nasm -fwin64 hello.asm && gcc hello.obj && a
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        global  main
        extern  puts
        section .text
main:
        sub     rsp, 28h                        ; Reserve the shadow space and align stack
        mov     rcx, message                    ; First argument is address of message
        call    puts                            ; puts(message)
        add     rsp, 28h                        ; Remove shadow space
        ret
message:
        db      'Hello', 0                      ; C strings need a zero byte at the end
```

Discussion at the bottom of [this page](https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmtutorial/)

Comment: I'm your upviote but there is a problem with this code. RSP isn't 16 byte aligned before calling `puts`. The stack is misaligned by 8 (because the return address was on the stack by the call instruction) when  `main` starts running. You might consider subtracting 28h instead to account for the shadow space and the alignment. The extra 8 will put the shadow space back on a 16 byte boundary. From the ABI: _The stack pointer must be aligned to 16 bytes in any region of code that isn’t part of an epilog or prolog, except within leaf functions._

Comment: Thank you, I will check it later. Another question: is there a way to print string by assembly and not by calling an external function?

Comment: @Omer : the alternative in Windows is calling the WinAPI to output directly. You'd have to use something like the [Windows Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) . The WInAPI is a wrapper around system calls (that may change from version to version) unlike Linux/BSD/MacOS etc.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelPetch - this code with the 20 byte adjustment worked two years ago by pure luck. Updated to 28.

Comment: This didn't work for me!! I have nasm version 2.14.02 and gcc version 8.1.0 Please help