# File format not recognized when trying build an exe from obj in windows

Tags: windows, assembly, gcc, nasm, mingw32

I was trying to build an exe from asm file. The asm file looks like this:

```
global main
extern puts

section .data

msg:
    db "Hello, world!",10,0

section .text

main:
    sub     rsp, 28h
    mov     rcx, msg
    call    puts
    add     rsp, 28h
    ret
```

Then I assembled it using NASM and tried to link it using GCC. But it is showing this error.

```
> nasm -fwin64 asmtest.asm
> gcc asmtest.obj
asmtest.obj: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am unable to figure out what is going on. My NASM version `2.14.02` and GCC version `8.1.0`. I have followed [this](https://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/nasmtutorial/) tutorial (at the bottom). I am doing this on my Windows 10 64-bit machine.

I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56716821/12357035) question, but it didn't help me.

Comment: "asmtest.obj" is in valid COFF format but `gcc` probably expects ELF, try to specify that with `--format` parameter. Shouldn't you also link your object file with some library file?

Comment: @vitsoft unrecognized command line option `--format` for GCC.

Comment: Which gcc toolchain do you use?  Make sure this is a 64 bit toolchain.

Comment: @fuz Yes, it says built with mingw-w64 beside version number.

Comment: @fuz oh sorry. That was indeed the error. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8659731/12357035) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7442838/12357035) answer.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Very good!  In the future, please state the exact toolchain you have installed in the question so this kind of thing is easy to stop.  Just a gcc version is not enough.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'exact toolchains' here? Example of what I should have included please.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB For example, what the complete name of the toolchain is and where you obtained it.  I don't know what name this would be for your case.  Reading your question, you have some mingw32 toolchain in some random version and variant.  And you only told us what the gcc version within that toolchain is, not what version or variant of mingw this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed mingw for 32 bit binaries.  You need to install a version of mingw configured to make 64 bit binaries to compile and/or link 64 bit binaries.